# What is the current security situation in Chisinau, Moldova?

Tags: security, photography, moldova

I'm planning on visiting Chișinău in the next month, mainly photographing architecture with a large DSLR during the day in the central part of town.

Has the recent war in Ukraine changed the security situation, or is it still relatively safe? Are there any places to avoid?

Comment: I've seen news reports of heightened *paranoia* regarding foreign spies.